# Multiple recipients of activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use [this (public_activity)](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem to create newsfeed. There is an recipient_id column, which is for one recipient of activity. But, in most cases, I have multiple recipients (e.g show activity to all people following a specific record) - the number of recipients can be more than 100, which is a lot of separate records to create at once and display.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

I found [this suggestion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/public-activity/aGfKjOV-LSE), although I can't get it to work and I get a lot of errors.

One solution might be to create a custom column

```
t.text :user_recipients
```

store ids of users who should get the activity (because, for example, they might be following a specific record). Then, check if current_user.id belongs_to that set of numbers. That set of numbers *("1, 3, 4")* would first be converted to an array *([1, 3, 4])* and we can use `array.include?(current_user.id)`

Is that a good way to do it?

Also, records that have an empty `user_recipients` column would not be shown.

At the end, we should get something like this:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(/records where current_user.id belongs to user_recipients array/ + /column is not empty/)
```

Comment: could you explain your model structure

Comment: what model specifically?

Comment: `user_recipents` what model does this belong to ? and why a text and not a separate table?

Comment: oh, that should be a custom_column in activities table - https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity#migration - that would store IDs of user who should get the activity. How would you go about doing this - is there a more efficient and better approach?

Comment: ok i see now, I haven't read the gem README, but can't this recipient relation be a table, this current method is kinda bad, the only way to handle this in a slightly more efficient way is to do a text search in the field using `like`

Comment: Could you write a full answer and fill in @activities variable ?

Comment: sure but could you explain the second part `column is not empty` ?

Comment: that's optional - there could be some errors when you have an empty set (no IDs in column). I've used this ".where.not(:user_recipients => nil)" and it seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching inside the string there's 4 possibilities

- id is in the beginning of the field
  ex: "id, 2, 3"
- id is in the end of the field
  ex: "1, 2, id"
- id is in the middle of the field
  ex: "1, id, 3"
- id is the only number in the field
  ex "id"

So here's how i think a query might look like

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(
  "user_recipients LIKE ':id,%' or 
   user_recipients LIKE '%, :id' or
   user_recipients LIKE '%, :id,%' or
   user_recipients = ':id'", id: current_user.id)
```

The reason why I can't do a simple `LIKE %id%` is that this would match partial numbers, meaning `id = 5` will match `[1, 10, 15]` though there's no `5`, but `15` does match, so I need to check for the commas `,` to make sure I'm not picking a wrong number.